# findAllByPk analog in Yii2

Tags: yii, yii2

How can i write query for ActiveRecord that will be an analog of [findAllByPk function](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#findAllByPk-detail) in yii?

I tried this:

```
$records = TableName::find($ids)->all();
```

But it doesn't work, returns all records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $ids is an array if primary keys like `[1, 3, 5, 23]`. You can use this

```
$entries = TableName::findAll($ids);
```

It is a short cut for this syntax

```
$entries = TableName::find()
                   ->where(['id'=>$ids])
                   ->all();
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `$ids` is an array,

```
$entries = TableName::find()
                ->where(['id'=>$ids])
                ->all();
```

Lots more examples [in the official docs.](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/db-active-record.md)

Comment: you missed square close bracket in `where` method argument